# How to sleep computer (Win10) remotely using Android phone?

Tags: windows, android, sleep, remote, phone

I was using Airytec Switch Off software which has a web interface and and ability to add and run own batch scripts so that's a nice solution even for some other tasks.

But it's not updated for some time now and I have some other issues with it.

What do you use for sleeping/shutting down remotely your computer or laptop using phone?

Comment: Do you have an SSH server on your PC? If so there is ssh client software for android that can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can install any Remote Desktop app on your phone, use it to connect to the PC* and there select Sleep in the Start menu.

If you want to do this while not in the home network, then you need some port forwarding etc, like described in the other answer.

* - on the PC you must enable Remote Desktop connections, it is in the System settings (just type "remote" in the start menu, it should find it)

Answer (score 0):

SSH is one of the simplest ways to accomplish this:

1. Instal [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) on the PC *([custom](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSH/Windows/sshd_config%20(Win32-OpenSSH)) Windows [`sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config))*
2. Install [JuiceSSH](https://juicessh.com/) on [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh)
3. Configure router with a [DDNS](https://www.lifewire.com/definition-of-dynamic-dns-816294), such as from [Dyn](https://dyn.com/remote-access/), unless ISP assigns your modem a static IP 
    *If choosing a paid provider like Dyn, it's cheaper to buy longer-term subscriptions (i.e. a 5yr)*
4. Configure a DNAT [port redirect](https://portforward.com/) *(port forwarding)* on your router

   - Forward an arbitrary WAN-side port to LAN-side PC's IP and SSH port 
      *It's recommended to forward a high WAN-side port `>30000` to the PC's LAN-side SSH port;  **Never** forward WAN-side port `22`, otherwise your router will be bombarded with hundreds to thousands of access attempts daily by port scanners*
5. Create your personal SSH keys via [`ssh-keygen`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen), setting a complex passphrase for each: 
    *(This cannot be stressed enough: All SSH keys should be encrypted with a secure passphrase)*

   ```powershell
   :: # Powershell # ::

     :: # ED25519:
          Ssh-Keygen -t ed25519 -E sha256 -C "$(echo $env:UserName) OpenSSH ED25519"

     :: # RSA:
          Ssh-Keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -E sha256 -C "$(echo $env:UserName) OpenSSH RSA"
   ```
6. Add the public key of each key to the PC user's `~\.ssh\authorized_keys` file:

   ```powershell
   :: # Powershell # ::

     :: # ED25519:
          Cat "~\.ssh\id_ed25519.pub" >> "~\.ssh\authorized_keys"
          Cat "~\.ssh\id_ed25519.pub" >> "~\.ssh\authorized_keys"

     :: # RSA:
          Cat "~\.ssh\id_rsa.pub" >> "~\.ssh\authorized_keys"
          Cat "~\.ssh\id_rsa.pub" >> "~\.ssh\authorized_keys"
   ```

   - Each key must be added twice for JuiceSSH, modifying the comment at the end of each duplicate in `~\.ssh\authorized_keys` to `JuiceSSH` within a text editor. 
      *After manually doing so, the `~\.ssh\authorized_keys` file will look like:*

     ```powershell
     ssh-ed25519 ... <username> OpenSSH ED25519
     ssh-ed25519 ... JuiceSSH
     ssh-rsa ... <username> OpenSSH RSA
     ssh-rsa ... JuiceSSH
     ```
7. Copy your `~\.ssh\id_ed25519` and `~\.ssh\id_rsa` to your Android phone, then open JuiceSSH 
    *(Android storage is accessible to all, making a passphrase protected SSH key a must)*

   1. Connections > Identities > +

      - **Nickname:** Set a name for this key 
         **Username:** Windows SSH username *(likely Windows username)* 
         **Private Key:** Set > Import > Smart Search
      - Save via the checkmark in the upper right corner and repeat #7.1 for each private key
   2. Connections > Connections > +

      - **Nickname:** Set a name for this connection 
         **Type:** SSH 
         **Address:** DDNS address or ISP static IP 
         **Identity:** Select previously created Identity 
         **Port:** WAN-side DNAT port configured on router in #4
      - Save via the checkmark in the upper right corner
8. Initiate SSH connection by selecting the connection profile created in #7.2
9. See [Suspend or Hibernate from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20713782/6819406) for different command options to suspend PC